# MATHEMATICA, How do I subtract the absolute magnitude of two different vectors in the xy plane?

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, physics

I need to evaluate an equation in Matlab:

Cos^2(|r1|-|r2|)

where

r1 = {x_1, y_1}
r2 = {x_2, y_2}

for all x_1, x_2 in the x and y_1, y_2 in the y.

I understand that this is likely an extraordinarily easy thing to do, but I'm brand new to this and I can't figure it out. Thanks.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: since r^2 = x^2+y^2 .. then | r | = sqrt(x^2+y^2) .. right?